# How to remove a string element from a list if its a subset of another element?

Tags: scala

This question is there on stackoverflow, the solution is in Python. Please help me with a solution in SCALA.

Quoting the query below:

---

So starting with a list of strings, as below

```
string_list = List('rest', 'resting', 'look', 'looked', 'it', 'spit')
```

I want to remove any element from the list that is a substring of another element, giving the result for instance...

```
string_list = ['resting', 'looked', 'spit']
```

---

How to achieve this in SCALA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
val list = List("rest", "resting", "look", "looked", "it", "spit")
val result = list.filter(item => !list.view.filter(_!=item).exists(_.contains(item)))
```

Comment: Thanks once again Nyavro. I am still learning and improving :)